# receive data from simulink block via udp

Tags: udp, raspberry-pi, simulink

I want to send data from a Simulink model (running in real time) to a Python script (also running in real time. I am using Simulink's built-in "UDP Send" block, which works. If simulink sends a constant "10", I get an output of (10.0,). but i want 10 as it is.

```
import sys, struct
from socket import *

SIZE = 1024      # packet size

hostName = gethostbyname('0.0.0.0')

mySocket  = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
mySocket.bind((hostName,18726))

repeat = True
if repeat:
    (data,addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
    data = struct.unpack('d',data)
    print data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 import sys, struct
 from socket import *

 SIZE = 1024      # packet size

 hostName = gethostbyname('0.0.0.0')

 mySocket  = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
 mySocket.bind((hostName,18726))

 repeat = True
 if repeat:
    (data,addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
    data = struct.unpack('d',data)
    print (int)data[0]
```